# cbind or merge by pasting names?

Tags: r, merge, xts, cbind

I have many large `xts` objects in my workspace that i am trying to combine by using `cbind` , `merge`,  `apply` or even in a loop. Currently, the `xts` data is tick data and cannot paste it here because of its length. However, what I am trying to do is:

```
cbind(AAPL.O, AMZN.O, BIDU.O, GLD.A, ...) -> all
```

by pasting using the following names on `cbind`

```
stock1 <- c("AAPL.O", "AMZN.O", "BIDU.O", "GLD.A", ...) # names of xts objects

# However this only combines the names "AAPL.O" & "AMZN.O"
cbind(paste(stock1[1]), paste(stock1[2]))
```

I have also tried `apply` :

```
apply(t(stock1), 2, cbind)
```

but it only combines the names as in `stock1`. I have also tried using:

```
merge(SPY.A, source [stock1])
```

but get the following error:
`Error in source[stock1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Since I can't put all the tick data in here I will provide some code to download data from online using `getSymbols()`

```
library(quantmod)

symbols <- c("AAPL", "AMZN", "BIDU", "GLD")

getSymbols(symbols)

#These will yield the same problem I am having
cbind(paste(symbols[1]),paste(symbols[2] ))  

apply(t(symbols), 2, cbind)

merge(AAPL, source [symbols])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a combination of `mget` and `do.call` would work for you, but it's hard to tell without some sample input and expected output.

An example:

```
## Some matrices to combine using `cbind`
M1 <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
M2 <- matrix(5:8, ncol = 2)
M3 <- matrix(9:10, ncol = 1)

## Like your "stock1"
Get <- c("M1", "M2", "M3")

do.call(cbind, mget(Get))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    3    5    7    9
# [2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I had never used `mget` before. Thanks!

Comment: @Rime, glad to hear it. And I see that you've updated your question with a reproducible example, so +1 for the effort there :-)